# Drupal6 reference URL date in views filter?

Tags: 6

I apologize if this is already explained somewhere, I haven't found it.

I have a view in drupal6 based on the date browser example.  I want to show all items having a date greater or equal than the date from the path:

for example, **#somesite#.com/events/2012-08-01**

- with **arguments** it shows events that are equal to the date in the
  path; can it show greater or equal?
- with **filters** it can show greater or equal to a hard-coded date,
  but can it reference the date from the path somehow?

Is there some other module or best way to do this?

Update: perhaps this is the answer [Date argument as view filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34382/date-argument-as-view-filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved this by using the "Views PHP Filter" http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter
after that i was able to choose Node PHP filter and added code to select the nodes based on the passed date like this:

```
$my_req = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

preg_match('/my_page\/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/', $my_req, $matches);

# Get the month from the URL or use the current month:
if(isset($matches[1])){
  $my_Y = $matches[1];
  $my_m = $matches[2];
  $my_date = $matches[3]+1;
} else {
  $my_Y = date("Y");
  $my_m = date("m");
  $my_date = date("d")+1;
}
$the_date = $my_Y . "-" . $my_m ."-". $my_date;
$nodeids = array();
$query = "SELECT nid FROM content_type_event WHERE field_start_value > \"$the_date\" AND field_start_value < DATE_ADD(\"$the_date\", INTERVAL + 16 DAY) ";

$my_result = db_query($query);
while ($my_row = db_fetch_array($my_result)) {
  $nodeids[] = $my_row['nid'];
}
return $nodeids;
```